# x86 assembly fading bmp with linear interpolation

Tags: x86, interpolation, intel, bmp, fading

The task is : Fade the top of a 24 bpp .BMP image to white so that every pixel's color is linearly interpolated 
between its original color and white based on its distance form the top edge. Pixels of distances >= 
dist are not faded.

I created all code and tried to fade something . It seems that it works only for distances which are power of 2 so 32,64,128 etc...
I am using linear interpolation equaction and i dont have any idea why it doesnt work for other numbers. 
Any ideas ? :).

Sample image:

[image: before]

After fading I am getting...
[image: after]

```
global fadetop

; parm.
%define     img         [ebp+8]
%define     width       [ebp+12]
%define     height      [ebp+16]
%define     dist        [ebp+20]
; local
%define     row_bytes      [ebp-4]
%define     dist_counter   [ebp-8]

fadetop:
; create stack frame
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 8

; push register on stack
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi

; calculate size of row 
mov     edx, width              
lea     edx, [edx+edx*2]        
add     edx, 3                  
and     edx, 0fffffffch         
mov     row_bytes, edx          

; address of datas -calculations to write pixels from top left corner
mov eax,height
mul edx
sub eax ,row_bytes
add eax,3
mov     esi, img
add esi,eax

;line couter 

xor edx, edx
mov dist_counter , edx
line:    
; pixel counter in line 
mov     edi, width

; index rexister 
xor     ebx, ebx

; INTERPOlATION STARTS NOW !!!


convert:                                  
movzx   eax, byte [esi+ebx+0]   ; take color 1
sub     eax, 255        ; sub white value
mov     ecx, dist_counter   
imul    ecx         ;color * actual position  
cdq
mov     ecx, dist       ; devide by full fade operation distance 
idiv    ecx
add     eax, 255        ; add 255 
mov     [esi+ebx+0], al     ;put in this place  

movzx   eax,byte [esi+ebx+1]    ; take color 2
sub     eax, 255
mov     ecx , dist_counter
mul     ecx
cdq
mov     ecx, dist
div     ecx
add     eax, 255
mov     [esi+ebx+1], al

movzx   eax,byte [esi+ebx+2]    ; take color 3
sub     eax, 255
mov     ecx , dist_counter
mul     ecx
cdq
mov     ecx, dist
div     ecx
add     eax, 255
mov     [esi+ebx+2], al

;________________________________________________________________
                    ;if still in one line 
    add     ebx, 3
    dec     edi
    jnz     convert

                        ; if next line 
sub     esi, row_bytes
mov     edx,dist_counter
inc     edx
mov     dist_counter,edx
mov     eax, dist
cmp     eax, edx      
jnz     line


    ; pop registers
    pop     edi
    pop     esi
    pop     ebx

    ; return trace         
    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

code in C for those who would like to run it and try fading :

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void fadetop(void* img, int width, int height ,int dist );

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    char* buff;

    if (argc != 3 ) {
        printf("Use file: %s [file]\n",argv[0]);
        return 1;

    }

    struct stat st;
    stat(argv[1], &st);

    buff = (char *) malloc(st.st_size);
    if (buff == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error!!\n");

        return 1;
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        printf("File access error\n");
        free(buff);

        return 1;
    }

    int size = read(fd, buff, st.st_size);
    uint32_t offset    = *(uint32_t *) (buff + 0x0a);
    uint32_t width    = *(uint32_t *) (buff + 0x12);
    uint32_t height    = *(uint32_t *) (buff + 0x16);
    uint16_t bpp    = *(uint16_t *) (buff + 0x1c);

    if (bpp == 24) {
        int fd_out;
        printf("worked dist: %d , heigh: %d\n", atoi(argv[2]), height);
        fadetop(buff + offset, width , height , atoi(argv[2]) );
        fd_out = creat("fade.bmp", 0644);
        write(fd_out, buff, size);
        close(fd_out);

        printf("Image faded.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid BMP\n");
    }

    close(fd);
    free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the intended use of your `dist` parameter? I think it can be replaced with `min(255,height)`. Can you add a link to a before/after image? Just post it on a public image server such as [imgur](http://imgur.com), and someone will insert it into your question.

Comment: I changed asm code a liitle bit. Instead of xoring edx in interpolation calculation part , i am doing cdq .There are images. [link1]http://i.imgur.com/RtGmj0q.png . I am processing this image and after fading I am getting... [link2]http://i.imgur.com/ooEn606.png .

Comment: dist parameter is used to hold full distance where it should be faded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems correct: you have something like

```
 color_new = (color-255)*dist_counter/dist + 255
```

although I would suggest the somewhat easier

```
color *= dist_counter/dist             ; scale original color over current dist
color += 256*(dist-dist_counter)/dist  ; add white, scaled over current dist
```

(which at least visually gives the same result). Your main error is that since you are *adding* to the current value, you may be overflowing the maximum value of 255. After the calculations, test if `color > 255` and clamp if it is.

In assembly (unable to test so I hope I get it right first time):

```
    movzx   eax, byte [esi+ebx+0]   ; take color 1
    mov     ecx, dist_counter   
    imul    ecx         ;color * current position
    cdq
    mov     ecx, dist       ; devide by full fade operation distance 
    idiv    ecx

    mov     ebx, eax        ; save result so far

    mov     eax, dist       ; calculate 2nd half
    mov     ecx, eax
    sub     eax, dist_counter
    shl     eax, 8
    idiv    ecx

    add     eax, ebx
    test    ah, ah
    jz      skip_clamp
    mov     al, 255
skip_clamp:
    mov     [esi+ebx+0], al     ;put in this place
```

.. repeated for your 3 color components.

A few additional notes which may be helpful:

1. My second line of calculating the `color` is a constant for each line. So you only have to calculate it in your y loop and save it somewhere.
2. You don't actually have to repeat the above code for each of the color components per pixel. Just repeat the x loop 3*`width`:

   ```
   mov     edi, width
   lea     edi, [edi+2*edi]
   ```
3. Your starting position seems off, not only by a few *lines* but by a few *pixels* as well. This is partly because of the `add eax,3` here:

   ```
   sub eax ,row_bytes
   add eax,3
   ```

   but I'm not sure where the larger error comes from, because your padding calculation is correct. I could not test your actual code so I implemented it in bare C, and with that I get the following output for the input `./a.out flower.bmp 400`:

[image: partially faded flower]

Comment: If you're going to use x86 asm, you should use the vector registers.  And then you can use `paddusb` to add packed bytes with unsigned saturation.